# Spring 4 Ehcache 3 Hibernate 5 cache default template setup

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

My project is on Spring 4.3.4, Hibernate 5.2.4 and Ehcache 3.3

I am looking for a solution with a singular JSR-107 (JCache) CacheManager for the whole the application to provide:

- Spring caching - with number of explicitly named Caches;
- Hibernate L2 caching - with the ability to implicitly generate any    number of regions (which are in fact the Caches too)

The main concern here is Hibernate. In fact, it is a question of setting a default template for its regions. After the review of a lot of topics I have not discovered a fully suitable solution.

So, if it exists, I'm kindly ask the experts to point to it. A programmatic only way of configuring is highly appreciated (ehcache.xml is unwanted).

**Added:** (in answer to @Anthony Dahanne):
I have already seen the solution in the project you are pointing for before I posted this topic. Even more, this project was the starting point of my investigation week ago.

But that solution is involving the explicit declaration of several named Cache regions not only for Spring, but even for Hibernate, as we can find in the [CacheConfiguration#createCacheConfigurations](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/terracotta/demo/config/CacheConfiguration.java#L72) method.

This is inconvenient in a real project which contains 100500 different Entities, NaturalKeys and so on, which are managed by Hibernate, because for all them it should create appropriate regions on the fly. I distinct the main power of Hibernate's RegionFactory as an ability to do this magic work automatically. But what we see in the pointed project in the [customized JCacheRegionFactory](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/terracotta/demo/config/jcache/JCacheRegionFactory.java) class? The direct ban for it to generate new regions, which is implemented by means of  unconditional exception that will be thrown on any attempt to do that (it is even noted with the "...but makes sure all caches are already existing to prevent spontaneous creation of badly configured caches..." comment).

The ideal solution must be able to set up a sole "default template" (on the CacheManager level) just like it works in case of encache.xml (...jcache:defaults default-template="myDefaultTemplate...), ...but without xml.

Comment: Hey Rostislav, hi. Did you find a solution, i guess it's not possible as per what Henri mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [JHipster fullstack demo example on ehcache3-samples github repo](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/tree/master/fullstack)

This example is based on Spring boot [programmatically sets up an ehcache3 cache](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/terracotta/demo/config/CacheConfiguration.java#L72), exposing it as [a JSR-107 CacheManager](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/terracotta/demo/config/CacheConfiguration.java#L68)

This cache is used [in conjunction with Hibernate](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml#L42) and [also independently](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/terracotta/demo/service/WeatherService.java#L49).

Comment: Dear Anthony Dahanne, thank you for your response! The JHipster project you are pointing on is a very useful as an example of the different caching aspects usage. But it uses an explicit way to define Hibernate's regions, that is not suitable for me. See my aditional explainations in my initial post. So, I cannot be fully satisfied with the offered solution and will continue  to ask.

Comment: Updated links (excluding line number anchors): ["programmatically sets up..."](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sample/config/CacheConfiguration.java), ["also independently"](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/blob/master/fullstack/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sample/service/WeatherService.java)

Answer (score 1):

We never want the default configuration (aka `new MutableConfiguration`). However, setting a meaningful default is acceptable. So indeed, in your case I would use a customized `JCacheRegionFactory`.

See [this article](http://blog.tremblay.pro/2017/02/jcache.html) about it.

Comment: Dear Henry! First, thanks for your link to your article. Also, I am a grateful investigator of your  "Ehcache 3 Samples" project. But I cannot be agree that Hibernate's regions should be defined explicitly. Look at my add in an initial post. I don't want to get "random default config". I wish to get it pre-configured without intervention into the Hibernate's RegionFactory, but simply by providing some basic configuration on the CacheManager level, like it is possible when we use ehcache.xml with defined "default-template". I wish to accomplish it programmatically in Java. Is it possible?

Comment: You are right, it is not possible to define templates programmatically. Mostly because reusing a method does almost the same. It is also more flexible. Why don't you want to extend `JCacheRegionFactory`? This is how you will get a preconfigured cache and a clean way to do it.